# Loop through find_element_by_name python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement

I have a code where it looks for a name and I am trying to write an if statement that says if it can't find that name look for something else.

What I have so far is as follows:

```
        excel = driver.find_element_by_name("Export to Excel")

        if excel == None:
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsimgspan']")
            search.click()

        else:
            excel.click()
```

I know what's inside the if statement works because I tested it out. Am I suppoed to change my argument in my if statement? The error I get is `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element` I tried entering "No such element" instead of "None" but I still get the same error. Also it tells me `Exception Unhandled NoSuchElementException('No such element', None, None)` can some give me advise on what I am doing wrong with the if statement? The error also say that it is found at `excel = driver.find_element_by_name("Export to Excel")` when the button isn't present in the page. When it is, it'll go straight to the else part of the statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_element_by_name method on your driver will raise the NoSuchElementException exception if it cannot find the webelement.

Try this

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    excel = driver.find_element_by_name("Export to Excel")
    excel.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2_lsimgspan']")
    search.click()
```

Comment: I tried that out and I got an error that said `except NoSuchElementException:
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined`

Comment: add the import statement from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException